# (php/oop) Method does not work in both directions

Tags: php, static-methods, method-chaining

I have somme issue in PHP, I put this code in my index.php :

```
$test = $wke ->sql
             ->insert("test")
             ->values(array("foo" => "bar"))
             ->go();
```

This code worked fine but when I use this code in an method (debug.class.php) like this :

```
$test = sql::insert("test")
             ->values(array("foo" => "bar"))
             ->go();
```

It doesn't work :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method template::values() [...]
```

My "insert" (and "values") method is in my SQL class, not my template class. I know that my second exemple is called in my template class but at in the end, I call sql::insert, not self::insert or template::insert. This is why I'm lost.

Sorry for my English ! Thank you in advance.

PS : This is my sql::insert method

```
static $queryBuffer;
public function insert($in) {
   self::$queryBuffer->type = "insert";
   self::$queryBuffer->data->insert = $in;
   return $this;
}
```

Comment: Since `insert` in your SQL class is not `static`, I don't think you can use `sql::insert`.

Answer (score -1):

Change your insert function as follows.

```
static $queryBuffer;
public static function insert($in) {
   self::$queryBuffer->type = "insert";
   self::$queryBuffer->data->insert = $in;
   return $this;
}
```

The insert should be static to call with the class name without the object.

Comment: But if you use `static` you can't use `return $this`.